# How can I set up a NAS on my PC and connect it to OneDrive?

Tags: nas, onedrive, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi 360 security camera, and can only connect to it using a NAS server. However, I want the data from the camera to be saved on my OneDrive storage.

Is it possible to use, say, 30GB of space on my PC as a network share and immediately download it to OneDrive (download not synchronize so new data could be saved later)? I have Windows 11 Home.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OneDrive software can backup your NAS, if you include the NAS
folder inside the OneDrive folder that is synced automatically.

You should create a symbolic link to the NAS folder inside the
OneDrive folder.

If for example the NAS is folder `N:\Data` and OneDrive uses
folder `OneDrive` inside the user profile folder:

- Run an elevated Command Prompt (CMD)
- Execute this command:

  ```
  mklink /j "%UserProfile%\OneDrive\Data" "D:\Data"
  ```
- To verify, see if in the OneDrive folder now exists
  a folder named `Data`.

Comment: Thanks. I have never worked with NAS before, so how I can setup NAS on my pc? for example I will create new disc D: and whant setup it as NAS.

Comment: You need in File Explorer to map the NAS folder to a drive-letter such as `D` or else.